# RxJS: clean way to pass data along observable chains?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I seem to run into this situation a lot where I am needing to pass data along a chain of streams. In other words, I have obervables that are dependent on the output of one or more other observables.

Below are 3 ways to do this with a simple example, but none of them feel like the "RxJS" way. Is there a better way to do this?

```
// Method #1 - looks clean, but feels hacky

let firstResponse = null;
performFirstAction().pipe(
  tap(_firstResponse => (firstResponse = _firstResponse)),
  switchMap(_firstResponse => performSecondAction(_firstResponse)),
  switchMap(secondResponse => performThirdAction(firstResponse, secondResponse))
);

// Method #2 - gets ugly real quick as it scales

performFirstAction().pipe(
  switchMap(firstResponse =>
    performSecondAction(firstResponse).pipe(
      map(secondResponse => ({ firstResponse, secondResponse }))
    )
  ),
  switchMap(({ firstResponse, secondResponse }) =>
    performThirdAction(firstResponse, secondResponse)
  )
);

// Method #3 - might as well just use callbacks at this point

performFirstAction().pipe(
  switchMap(firstResponse =>
    performSecondAction(firstResponse).pipe(
      switchMap(secondResponse =>
        performThirdAction(firstResponse, secondResponse)
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: Method#2 and Method#3 both are rxjs way. The only difference is - In #2 your observable chain is NOT nested [scopped to one level] but in #3 it is pretty nested so I feel there is a readability issue [technically #3 is absolutely fine]. In #1 you are maintaining a state outside of observable chain so its not rxjs way.

Comment: I guess i'm conflicted because though #2 & #3 aren't hacky, they don't feel very readable to me. I'm just wondering if there is a better way to do this that is readable like #1, yet not hacky.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest and most readable way to do this is to **store the intermediary Observables in their own variables**.

```
const firstResponse$ = performFirstAction();

const secondResponse$ = firstResponse$.pipe(
  switchMap(firstResponse => performSecondAction(firstResponse)),
);

const thirdResponse$ = secondResponse$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(firstResponse$),
  switchMap(([secondResponse, firstResponse]) => performThirdAction(firstResponse, secondResponse))
);
```

Comment: I think it should be `switchMap([secondResponse, firstResponse] => performThirdAction(firstResponse, secondResponse))`

Answer (score 0):

there is another approach for your scenario

```
performFirstAction().pipe(
  switchMap(first =>
    performSecondAction(first).pipe(mergeMap(second=>performThirdAction(first, second)))
    )
  ),
);
```

basically you are having `first` as local variable, so if you have fourth call you can using similar pattern and nest them.

and if you need a common pattern, you try `mergeScan` by creating higher order function to return observable. Here `acc` is always the last observable returned value

```
from([first,first=>second(first),second=>third(second)])
.pipe(mergeScan((acc,currObs)=>currObs(acc),null))
```